# How to convert MySQL to SQL Azure? ( Wordpress database )

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-sql-database

How to convert MySQL to SQL Azure? I have a Wordpress site, and I would like to put it to Azure Platform. How can I achieve it? It seems not easy.

Any shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [WordPress on Microsoft](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/) site? If you are talking about moving all of your current posts, I assume you can [export and import your data using the administration panels](http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/).

Comment: We are using the Microsoft WordPress version already. The SQLSRV library is buggy at this moment, which leads to quite a large amount of plugins not functioning. We are still looking workarounds / patches from Microsoft.